# access local sails variable in angular

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I am passing in two variables to my view. How can I access this variable from an angular controller?

**Sails Controller:**

```
return res.view('dashboard', {
    me: {
      id: user.id,
      apiKey: user.connection.apiKey
    }
 });
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
angular.module('DashboardModule').controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("/api/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.me.apiKey));
  .success(function(response) {$scope.records = response.records;});
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<h5>Api Key:</h5>
  <p ng-model="me.apiKey"><%= me.apiKey %></p>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in records">
      {{ x.guiLoginName }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

As you can see I am trying to perform a GET to a specific apiKey which is a variable. This variable is accessible from EJS but not angular. What am I doing wrong? To be fair, I fundamentally don't understand how sails communicates with angular...

Comment: did you find a better way than the checked answer? if you please post. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sails doesn't communicate with Angular, as simple as that. Sails is front-end agnostic.

You can render your `locals` variables to your template because there's a template pass when you call `res.view()` but that basically sets your `<%= me.apiKey %>` block.

What you could do is:

- make the variables available in the location, and get them through the route params (look up ui-router).
- pass it via the window object of the browser:

In your template:

```
<script>
    var apiKey = <%= me.apiKey %>;
</script>
```

and then in Angular you could recover them as:

```
app.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', '$window',
    function ($scope, $window) {
        $scope.apiKey = $window.apiKey;
    }
]);
```

Comment: Is this the only way to pass sails locals to angular?

Comment: I don't think it's the only way, but I'm sure there's no one-off solution, Sails is front-end agnostic, meaning that you can use any tool to make an interface to your API, not just angular.